# Flash sending 2 variables to php script, 1 of them being xml

Tags: php, xml, flash, actionscript-3

So this is probably a simple question, but for some reason, I'm having problems with it. I have no ideia why, but I suspect the fact that sending a xml with full "< something >" tags may cause the php to behave wrongly.

So all I need is to send (from a swf as3 client) a filename and a xml. The php will write a xml file with the required filename.

Everything should be okay with the php side, because I tried it using " $_GET " variables, but  whenever I try using the flash client, It just doesent work, and the php log says that "the filename variable can't be empty". Whenever I try some static filename (not using GET or POST), it works.

Sooo... Can someone help me out with this one?
Thanks.

EDIT: Code added.

```
var xmlURLReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("www.url.com");
    var test:URLVariables = new URLVariables;
    test.filename = "01.xml";
    test.xmldata = xmltosave;
    xmlURLReq.data = teste;
    xmlURLReq.contentType = "text/xml";
    xmlURLReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

    var xmlSendLoad:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    xmlSendLoad.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete, false, 0, true);
    xmlSendLoad.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError, false, 0, true);
    xmlSendLoad.load(xmlURLReq);

    var alertBox:alertBoxClass = new alertBoxClass();
    alertBox.x = 0;
    alertBox.y = 200;

    function onComplete(evt:Event):void 
    { 
        try 
        {
            var xmlResponse = new XML(evt.target.data);
            alertBox.alertText.text = "Inserção de dados bem sucedida!";
            addChild(alertBox);
            removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
            removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
            writeXML()
        }
    }
```

I also tried Object and LoadVars classes instead of URLVariables, no luck so far.

EDIT: Might as well add the php code as well.

```
<?php
    $filename = "http://url.com/".$_POST["filename"];
    $xml = $_POST["xmldata"];
    $file = fopen($filename , "wb");
    fwrite($file, $xml);
    fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: Post some of your actionscript code. There is a limit to how much you can send with a GET, so you might want to try POST instead.

Comment: Edited with the code. I did use POST, I just used GET in the browser to check it.

Comment: My PHP is a bit rusty, but shouldn't that me $_POST when using the method POST? Or is $_GET the "universal" one?

Comment: Erm, lol sorry, that was wrong because I was making experiments. But changed to POST and still has the same problem. Just edited the code again with the POST, which is what I have now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see one possible problem in your code;
You are setting the data to a URLVariables instance, but the contentType to "text/xml". It should be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" when using URLVariables.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#contentType

Hope that solves it!

Comment: Just tried that, but still not writing file. I always get a error log with a :  fopen(URL) [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in URL/insertclient.php on line 8

Comment: Could you try logging the generated path ($filename) from the PHP file to see what it receives?

Comment: I'm a bit newby with php, can you tell me how to do that? I usually do "echo ($filename)", but since this is a comand coming from flash, I dont have a output windows. Is there a way to get it on the error_log?

Comment: I think error_log($filename) should do it. Haven't worked in PHP for years unfortunatley, so I'm a bit rusty. Might be easier to echo it and then print it from flash (evt.target.data iirc).

Comment: It actually gets the rights path. http://url.com/gestao/xml/01.xml (that's not the real xml, but I'm using an example of what should be created).

Comment: So the problem should be in the PHP then. Can you write to that path?

Comment: Changed $filename = "fullpath/01.xml" and $xml = "blabla".

Now the error returned is : [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in /home/converte/public_html/gestao/php/insertclient.php on line 10.

That's awkward because I was able to write files a while back.

Comment: Okay, so I found out what was wrong! The problem was that I had a absolute URL, and aparently that is not allowed in php, even if its in the local server. So, all I had to do was change to relative path (like "../xml/01.xml") and it works now! You probably fixed the flash part with your original answer. So, Thanks!